# How to write a BLOB from db to the OS file system?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, blob

Is there a simple way to write a `BLOB` from `db` to a `OS` file system? Currently I have a lot of code which can do this but wondering if there are alternatives/easier methods. It seems that Oracle should provide a utility to perform a lot of this work for the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you need this programmatically or just as an ad-hoc operation.

Our GUI allows for this. I talk about [how to work with BLOBs in Oracle SQL Developer here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-quick-tip-blobs-and-images/).

In the BLOB dialog, there's a download link you can use to save the BLOB to a local file.